# Help to verify (numerically) invariant Haar measure on unitary group

Tags: group-theory, integration, calculus

Sorry if this question is not appropriate for the forum. From the paper http://gemma.ujf.cas.cz/~brauner/files/Haar_measure.pdf I am interested to understand and verify equation (3). Can anyone please help?

My present state: As I understand the measure defined on (3) on the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix is invariant. Does this mean that the scalar we would get from the equation (3) is same for unitary matrix? I am considering the eigenvectors of a square Hermitian matrix as an example of Unitary matrix. Now how can I generate the measure? If I do eigen-decompostion again on the eigenvector matrix I will get the complex eigenvalues, what else should I do to verify the equation?

Comment: Can you actually write out equation 3 (& relevant exposition) so that we don't have to download the document to figure out what you're talking about?